# How to copy/move/delete files from the shell?

Tags: shell, file-management

It's surely easy to do while using a graphical environment, but when I'm using the shell I have no idea on how to do that, I already tried to use `copy`, `move`, `delete`, and I discovered that these word are not existent commands on the shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are:

- Copy: `cp file_name <directory|file_name>`
- Move: `mv file_name <directory|file_name>`
- Delete: `rm file_name`

Visit their `man` pages for more information.

Comment: Note that the command descriptions are incomplete/incorrect. For `cp` and `mv` the 2nd parameter can be, and quite frequently is, a file name, it doesn't have to be a directory.

Comment: @Levon: Thank you. Added the other possibility. Keeping it simple.

Answer (score 10):

The commands you are looking for are: [cp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp), [mv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) and [rm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) - but that won't help you past those specific tasks.

You'd really benefit from reading basic tutorials (see links below) on using a Linux/Unix system from the command line, or picking up an intro text from your local library. If you are somewhat familiar with the Windows command shell, then you will find some basic similarities (of course the commands are still different).

In the meantime, check out the manual (a.k.a. [man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)) pages. To find out more about them you can type

```
man man
```

at the command prompt.

Another *very* useful command line switch to use with `man` is `-k`, it will list commands related to the search term you list. For instance

```
man -k delete
```

will list all the commands that have to do with "delete". Of course you have to be somewhat selective in what you search on. A `man -k file` will get you tons of commands since most commands do something with files :)

I just did this google search: "how to use the unix command line" and found a bunch of pages. Here are 3 that might be helpful:

- [Learn Unix in 10 minutes](http://freeengineer.org/learnUNIXin10minutes.html)
- [Basic Unix Commands](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html)
- [A Beginner's Guide to Unix](http://www.osc.edu/supercomputing/unix-cmds.shtml)

and I bet there are some intro videos on [youTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=basic+linux+shell+commands&oq=basic+linux&gs_l=youtube.3.6.0l8.1677.6180.0.9986.17.14.3.0.0.0.151.1121.10j4.14.0...0.0...1ac.xa8Njrrtu2s) (<- ***check*** this link :) too.

Comment: TLDP has always been a great source for initial learning:
http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/intro-linux.html